# Earned today should be Badges earned today?

Tags: discussion, tooltips

In the following image:

[image: screenshot of popup]

should it be ***badges earned today*** instead of ***earned today*** ? Don't you think so?

Comment: Couldn't fabricate a better excuse to show us your Pundit badge?  :-)

Comment: @Rick: I'm not advertising my badges.

Comment: Just teasing.  Your premise is very weak though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's quite clear these are badges, no need to waste an space in that panel.

Answer (score 1):

Mat is right, it's clear that this is about badges, but "*today*" is rather misleading: Unless [this bug report of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85303/misleading-earned-today-for-badges-in-the-drop-down-menu) is completed, it should read "earned in the last 24 hours" as suggested by Grace Note. (To be clear, I'm not talking about time zones here: even if I got a badge yesterday 22:00 UTC, today it'll still show up as "earned today".)

Comment: The behavior here is consistent with a "day" everywhere else on the site. It would be even more confusing to change *just* this.

Comment: @Cody: The behaviour is **not** consistent. I had a "favorite" change 17 hours ago, but in the dropdown it says "0" under "today". So _the other instance of today_ in the dropdown (with 4 entries!) has a different meaning. _This_ is confusing, isn't it?